# Are there any binary values that don't have exact representation in decimal?

Tags: floating-point, computer-science, precision

We all know that there are values in *decimal* that don't have an exact representation in binary.

For example the decimal value `0.1`.

In IEEE floating point format it can have different representations depending on how many bits you want to dedicate to representing a floating-point value.

**Single Precision** (32-bits)

- **Hex**: 0x3DCCCCCD
- **Binary**: 1.10011001100110011001101×10<sup>-4</sup>
- **Decimal**: 0.10000 00014 90116 11938 47656 25

**Double Precision** (64-bits)

- **Hex**: 0x3FB999999999999A
- **Binary**: 1.1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010×10<sup>-4</sup>
- **Decimal**: 0.10000 00000 00000 00555 11151 23125 78270 21181 58340 45410 15625

**Extended Precision** (80-bits)

- **Hex**: 0x3FFBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCD
- **Binary**: 1.100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101×10<sup>-4</sup>
- **Decimal**: 0.10000 00000 00000 00000 13552 52715 60688 05425 09316 00108 74271 39282 22656 25

In other words, the decimal value `0.1` does not have an exact representation in binary, it is endlessly repeating value:

```
0.0 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 ...
0.0 ̅0̅0̅1̅1
```

In the same way 1⁄3 has no exact representation in decimal - its digits after *"decimal point"* keep repeating forever:

```
0.33333 33333 33333 33333 33333 33333 33333 ...
0.̅3
```

### But does it go the other way?

Are there any values in binary that don't have an exact representation in decimal?

Why am I asking? To extend the bounds of understanding, and add to the sum of human knowledge.

**Edit**: I don't know why someone is voting to close as a duplicate when the linked question is literally the exact **opposite** of mine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)  Some of the answers address it indirectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, every binary floating-point number has an exact representation in decimal.

The numbers that can be represented exactly in binary floating-point (with a finite number of bits) are precisely those rational numbers which can be written with a denominator which is a power of 2, i.e. *x* = *a*/2<sup>*n*</sup> for integers *a* and *n*.

The numbers that can be represented exactly in binary floating-point (with a finite number of digits) are precisely those rational numbers which can be written with a denominator which is a power of 10, i.e. *y* = *b*/10<sup>*n*</sup>.

But every number from the first category is also in the second category, since *a*/2<sup>*n*</sup> = *a*•5<sup>*n*</sup>/10<sup>*n*</sup>.

More generally, every number with an exact representation in base *u* will also have an exact representation in base *v*, if and only if every prime factor of *u* is also a prime factor of *v*.  This will ensure that 1/*u*<sup>*n*</sup> can be written as *a*/v<sup>*m*</sup> for some *a* and *m*.

This explains the asymmetry: 2 is prime, and the prime factors of 10 are 2 and 5.  So every prime factor of 2 is a prime factor of 10, but not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks @Eric for the formatting improvements.  I get spoiled by the sites that support MathJax.

Comment: The floating-point form is more commonly written as a•b^n rather than a/b^n, although of course they are equivalent as n is an integer iff −n is an integer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Thanks, I meant to say "every number".  Fixed.

Comment: A bit of nitpicking: I believe you can represent every decimal as a binary floating point number so long as you do not require the representation to be finite.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks, edited to mention this.