# Playground Crash: "error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGKILL." Seeking techniques to simplify code

Tags: swift, swift-playground

My project involves creating a table of data with a row for each of the 12 months of the year. The user of the app will define their monthly pay and percentage of pay they want to contribute to his/her 401k. The table shows in which month the user has reached the IRS contribution limit ($22,500) and consequently cannot contribute any more until next year.

I'm using Xcode playground to test my formulae.  Since each month from February through December must look back at contributions and sums from the previous months, there is a considerable amount of looping which drives excessive execution time.  I have a computed variable titled "personal401kContributionMonthly" which computes what the user has defined for their desired percent of monthly pay to contribute to their 401k.  This computed property ran 4,940,531 times before the playground crashed with the following error: "error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGKILL. [12211:365921] Unable to quarantine process. (Error: -1.)"

I am seeking for advice/techniques to simplify the code to avoid the crash.

```
var monthlyPay = 15203.0
var personal401kLimit = 22500.0
var personal401kPercentage = 10.0
var roth401kPercentage = 10.0
var personal401kContributionMonthly: Double {
    monthlyPay * (personal401kPercentage/100)
}
personal401kContributionMonthly

var persTradContJan: Double {
    personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? (personal401kContributionMonthly * (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100))) : personal401kLimit * (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100))
}
persTradContJan
var persRothContJan: Double {
    roth401kPercentage == 0.0 ? 0.0 : personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (roth401kPercentage/100) : personal401kLimit * (roth401kPercentage/100)
}
persRothContJan
var pers401ksumFeb: Double {
    persTradContJan + persRothContJan
}
var persTradContFeb: Double {
    pers401ksumFeb + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) : pers401ksumFeb < personal401kLimit ? (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) * (personal401kLimit - (pers401ksumFeb)) : 0.0
}
persTradContFeb
var persRothContFeb: Double {
    roth401kPercentage == 0.0 ? 0.0 : pers401ksumFeb + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (roth401kPercentage/100) : pers401ksumFeb < personal401kLimit ? (roth401kPercentage/100) * (personal401kLimit - pers401ksumFeb) : 0.0
}
persRothContFeb
var pers401ksumMar: Double {
    persTradContJan + persRothContJan + persTradContFeb + persRothContFeb
}
var persTradContMar: Double {
    pers401ksumMar + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) : pers401ksumMar < personal401kLimit ? (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) * (personal401kLimit - (pers401ksumMar)) : 0.0
}
persTradContMar
var persRothContMar: Double {
    roth401kPercentage == 0.0 ? 0.0 : pers401ksumMar + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (roth401kPercentage/100) : pers401ksumMar < personal401kLimit ? (roth401kPercentage/100) * (personal401kLimit - pers401ksumMar) : 0.0
}
persRothContMar
var pers401ksumApr: Double {
    persTradContJan + persRothContJan + persTradContFeb + persRothContFeb + persTradContMar + persRothContMar
}
var persTradContApr: Double {
    pers401ksumApr + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) : pers401ksumApr < personal401kLimit ? (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) * (personal401kLimit - (pers401ksumApr)) : 0.0
}
persTradContApr
var persRothContApr: Double {
    roth401kPercentage == 0.0 ? 0.0 : pers401ksumApr + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (roth401kPercentage/100) : pers401ksumApr < personal401kLimit ? (roth401kPercentage/100) * (personal401kLimit - pers401ksumApr) : 0.0
}
persRothContApr
var pers401ksumMay: Double {
    persTradContJan + persRothContJan + persTradContFeb + persRothContFeb + persTradContMar + persRothContMar + persTradContApr + persRothContApr
}
var persTradContMay: Double {
    pers401ksumMay + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) : pers401ksumMay < personal401kLimit ? (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) * (personal401kLimit - (pers401ksumMay)) : 0.0
}
persTradContMay
var persRothContMay: Double {
    roth401kPercentage == 0.0 ? 0.0 : pers401ksumMay + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (roth401kPercentage/100) : pers401ksumMay < personal401kLimit ? (roth401kPercentage/100) * (personal401kLimit - pers401ksumMay) : 0.0
}
persRothContMay
var pers401ksumJun: Double {
    persTradContJan + persRothContJan + persTradContFeb + persRothContFeb + persTradContMar + persRothContMar + persTradContApr + persRothContApr + persTradContMay + persRothContMay
}
var persTradContJun: Double {
    pers401ksumJun + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) : pers401ksumJun < personal401kLimit ? (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) * (personal401kLimit - (pers401ksumJun)) : 0.0
}
persTradContJun
var persRothContJun: Double {
    roth401kPercentage == 0.0 ? 0.0 : pers401ksumJun + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (roth401kPercentage/100) : pers401ksumJun < personal401kLimit ? (roth401kPercentage/100) * (personal401kLimit - pers401ksumJun) : 0.0
}
persRothContJun
var pers401ksumJul: Double {
    persTradContJan + persRothContJan + persTradContFeb + persRothContFeb + persTradContMar + persRothContMar + persTradContApr + persRothContApr + persTradContMay + persRothContMay + persTradContJun + persRothContJun
}
var persTradContJul: Double {
    pers401ksumJul + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) : pers401ksumJul < personal401kLimit ? (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) * (personal401kLimit - (pers401ksumJul)) : 0.0
}
persTradContJul
var persRothContJul: Double {
    roth401kPercentage == 0.0 ? 0.0 : pers401ksumJul + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (roth401kPercentage/100) : pers401ksumJul < personal401kLimit ? (roth401kPercentage/100) * (personal401kLimit - pers401ksumJul) : 0.0
}
persRothContJul
var pers401ksumAug: Double {
    persTradContJan + persRothContJan + persTradContFeb + persRothContFeb + persTradContMar + persRothContMar + persTradContApr + persRothContApr + persTradContMay + persRothContMay + persTradContJun + persRothContJun + persTradContJul + persRothContJul
}
var persTradContAug: Double {
    pers401ksumAug + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) : pers401ksumAug < personal401kLimit ? (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) * (personal401kLimit - (pers401ksumAug)) : 0.0
}
persTradContAug
var persRothContAug: Double {
    roth401kPercentage == 0.0 ? 0.0 : pers401ksumAug + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (roth401kPercentage/100) : pers401ksumAug < personal401kLimit ? (roth401kPercentage/100) * (personal401kLimit - pers401ksumAug) : 0.0
}
persRothContAug
var pers401ksumSep: Double {
    persTradContJan + persRothContJan + persTradContFeb + persRothContFeb + persTradContMar + persRothContMar + persTradContApr + persRothContApr + persTradContMay + persRothContMay + persTradContJun + persRothContJun + persTradContJul + persRothContJul + persTradContAug + persRothContAug
}
var persTradContSep: Double {
    pers401ksumSep + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) : pers401ksumSep < personal401kLimit ? (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) * (personal401kLimit - (pers401ksumSep)) : 0.0
}
persTradContSep
var persRothContSep: Double {
    roth401kPercentage == 0.0 ? 0.0 : pers401ksumSep + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (roth401kPercentage/100) : pers401ksumSep < personal401kLimit ? (roth401kPercentage/100) * (personal401kLimit - pers401ksumSep) : 0.0
}
persRothContSep
var pers401ksumOct: Double {
    persTradContJan + persRothContJan + persTradContFeb + persRothContFeb + persTradContMar + persRothContMar + persTradContApr + persRothContApr + persTradContMay + persRothContMay + persTradContJun + persRothContJun + persTradContJul + persRothContJul + persTradContAug + persRothContAug + persTradContSep + persRothContSep
}
var persTradContOct: Double {
    pers401ksumOct + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) : pers401ksumOct < personal401kLimit ? (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) * (personal401kLimit - (pers401ksumOct)) : 0.0
}
persTradContOct
var persRothContOct: Double {
    roth401kPercentage == 0.0 ? 0.0 : pers401ksumOct + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (roth401kPercentage/100) : pers401ksumOct < personal401kLimit ? (roth401kPercentage/100) * (personal401kLimit - pers401ksumOct) : 0.0
}
persRothContOct
var pers401ksumNov: Double {
    persTradContJan + persRothContJan + persTradContFeb + persRothContFeb + persTradContMar + persRothContMar + persTradContApr + persRothContApr + persTradContMay + persRothContMay + persTradContJun + persRothContJun + persTradContJul + persRothContJul + persTradContAug + persRothContAug + persTradContSep + persRothContSep + persTradContOct + persRothContOct
}
var persTradContNov: Double {
    pers401ksumNov + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) : pers401ksumNov < personal401kLimit ? (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) * (personal401kLimit - (pers401ksumNov)) : 0.0
}
persTradContNov
var persRothContNov: Double {
    roth401kPercentage == 0.0 ? 0.0 : pers401ksumNov + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (roth401kPercentage/100) : pers401ksumNov < personal401kLimit ? (roth401kPercentage/100) * (personal401kLimit - pers401ksumNov) : 0.0
}
persRothContNov
var pers401ksumDec: Double {
    persTradContJan + persRothContJan + persTradContFeb + persRothContFeb + persTradContMar + persRothContMar + persTradContApr + persRothContApr + persTradContMay + persRothContMay + persTradContJun + persRothContJun + persTradContJul + persRothContJul + persTradContAug + persRothContAug + persTradContSep + persRothContSep + persTradContOct + persRothContOct + persTradContNov + persRothContNov
}
var persTradContDec: Double {
    pers401ksumDec + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) : pers401ksumDec < personal401kLimit ? (1 - (roth401kPercentage/100)) * (personal401kLimit - (pers401ksumDec)) : 0.0
}
persTradContDec
var persRothContDec: Double {
    roth401kPercentage == 0.0 ? 0.0 : pers401ksumDec + personal401kContributionMonthly <= personal401kLimit ? personal401kContributionMonthly * (roth401kPercentage/100) : pers401ksumDec < personal401kLimit ? (roth401kPercentage/100) * (personal401kLimit - pers401ksumDec) : 0.0
}
persRothContDec
```

UPDATE 1:

The intent of this 401k project is to also incorporate employer direct contributions and "back-door-Roth" overflow into a 401a account.  Consequently I believe I will need to store and initialize the sum of contributions month-to-month because this running total will need to be referenced for calculating each month's 401a contributions.

For example, some employers offer the "back-door" option which allows an employee who has reached the individual contribution limit ($22,500) to continue contributing that year but those funds are deposited into a 401a (not 401k).  But once the sum total of a) personal contributions, b) company contributions (match or direct deposit) and c) 401a "back-door" contributions reach the IRS limit for combined contributions ($66,000), then an employee can no longer contribute to his/her 401a account.

In order to show how much an employee would contribute to their 401a account for Jan, Feb, Mar, etc., I need to reference the previous month totals.  For example, for the February print iteration, the formula for 401a contributions needs to reference the sum total of personal contributions in January and February.  Using the wonderful example of code provided by Chip Jarred (thank you!!), if we set the value of monthly to 15203.0 and the personal401kPercentage to 100% (for demonstration purposes only), this would be the result:

[image: playground snip 1]

The sum total of $1,520, $13,683, $730, & $6,567 equals $22,500.  But the sum of February only ($730 & $6,567 = $7,297) is less than the amount the employee would like to contribute (100% of monthly pay: $15,203).   Consequently, in February the 401a deposit should be $7,906 ($730 + $6,567 + **$7,906** = $15,203).

In my view, the first step in achieving this functionality is to store and set in the initializer the cumulative totals for personal contributions for each month.  (Later we will probably need the cumulative totals for company **AND** personal contributions in order to know when we've reached $66,000 in order to stop contributing the 401a account.  But we can probably address that later).

Here is my attempt at adding a yearToDate property to MonthlyContributions....

```
extension MonthlyContributions
{
var total: Decimal { roth + traditional }

init(combinedAmount: Decimal, rothPercentage: Decimal)
{
    let roth = roundToNearestPenny(
        percentage: rothPercentage,
        of: combinedAmount
    )
    self.init(roth: roth, traditional: combinedAmount - roth)
}
}
extension MonthlyContributions
{
var yearToDate: Decimal { total }

init(combinedAmount: Decimal, limit: Decimal)
{
    let totalContributions = calculateCombinedContribution(
        monthlyContribution       : total,
        annualContributionLimit   : limit,
        contributionsSoFarThisYear: yearToDate
    )
}
}
```

Unfortunately this was unsuccessful as using

```
    print("    Total      : $\(curContribution.yearToDate)")
```

only prints singular month totals, not a running cumulative total.

Comment: Use an array and calculate everything just once. Using nested computed properties where some of the computed properties are called over and over when the value doesn't change is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Could this be a (wait for it) stack overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your playground crashes because all those computed variables reference other computed variables in ways that explode the call tree exponentially, so as @matt, with tongue in cheek, pointed out in comments, it's a literal stack overflow.  Computed variables are just syntactic sugar for function calls.  Were you intending lazy assignment instead?

In any case, you asked about refactoring the code.

I think your example is the kind of thing that wants to be in a data structure where you index by the month rather than having individually named computed variables.  As is often the case, it can be accomplished multiple ways.  What follows is one way.  I'll break into part.

I'm going to assume that your playground is intended as a sort of prototyping environment for some code that you want to use in a real app.  If it's just a learning exercise, using `Double` to represent money is fine, but binary floating point types can't exactly represent all decimal numbers.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68943707/are-there-any-binary-values-that-dont-have-exact-representation-in-decimal) for examples and why this is the case. For this reason it's better to use `Decimal`, so that's what I'll do.

Unfortunately `Decimal` is slow compared to `Double` or `Float`, and doesn't have the most fully supported API in `Swift`. Actually its Objective-C counterpart, `NSDecimalNumber` is pretty crufty in Objective-C too.  Still, it is the best standardly available type to do financial computations.

Next I don't see any explicit rounding in your code example, and as far as I know fractional penny contributions to 401ks (or IRAs) are not a thing, so you need a way to round to whole pennies.  It's probably the most awkward code I'm going to present, so let's get it out of the way first.

There are two ways to do rounding on `Decimal`, and unfortunately neither of them are especially convenient. Unlike `Double`, `Decimal` does *not* provide `.rounded()` method.

One way is to call the `NSDecimalRound` free function, which requires getting a pointer to the value to round.  I'd probably use that way in my own code, but let's avoid pointers.

The second way is to make use of the fact that `Decimal` bridges to `NSDecimalNumber` which provides a `rounding(accordingToBehavior:)` method.  That requires creating a `NSDecimalNumberBehaviors` instance that configures how the rounding will be done... Did I mention the API is crufty?  We have to cast to `NSDecimalNumber` then call `rounding(accordingToBehavior:)` and then cast back to `Decimal`.  It looks like this:

```swift
import Foundation

let pennyRoundingBehavior = NSDecimalNumberHandler(
    roundingMode: .bankers,
    scale: 2,
    raiseOnExactness: false,
    raiseOnOverflow: true,
    raiseOnUnderflow: true,
    raiseOnDivideByZero: true
)

/**
 Computes `dollarAmount * percentage`, rounded to the nearest penny.
 
 Uses "Banker's" rounding: If truncated digits represent a value greater than
 half a penny, the result is rounded up.  If it's less than half a penny, the
 result is rounded down.  If it's exactly half a penny, the value is rounded to
 the nearest even penny.  So `10.015 is rounded to `10.02`, while `10.025` is
 also rounded to `10.02`.
 
 - Parameters:
    - percentage: `Decimal` value in the range 0...100
    - amount: `Decimal` to which `percentage` is applied.
 */
func roundToNearestPenny(percentage: Decimal, of dollarAmount: Decimal) -> Decimal
{
    assert((0...100).contains(percentage))
    
    let x = ((dollarAmount * percentage / 100) as NSDecimalNumber)
    return x.rounding(accordingToBehavior: pennyRoundingBehavior) as Decimal
}
```

Fortunately, all the other math we need to do with `Decimal` can be done just like for `Double`.

Since you want contributions per month, I define an `enum` to represent months:

```swift
enum ContributionMonth: Int, CaseIterable
{
    case January, February, March, April, May, June,
         July, August, September, October, November, December
    
    static var count:Int  { allCases.count }
}
```

I represent the contributions for a given month as a `struct`

```swift
struct MonthlyContributions
{
    var roth        : Decimal = 0
    var traditional : Decimal = 0
}

extension MonthlyContributions
{
    var total: Decimal { roth + traditional }
    
    init(combinedAmount: Decimal, rothPercentage: Decimal)
    {
        let roth = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: rothPercentage,
            of: combinedAmount
        )
        self.init(roth: roth, traditional: combinedAmount - roth)
    }
}
```

Note the `init` in the extension computes the contribution distribution, which will simplify later code.

Since I'll be storing instances of `MonthlyContributions` in an `Array` with elements that correspond to the months starting with `January` it would be nice to just index that array by the month.  To do that I extend `Array` when it holds `MonthlyContributions` as elements:

```swift
extension Array where Element == MonthlyContributions {
    subscript (index: ContributionMonth) -> Element { self[index.rawValue] }
}
```

An alternative would be to use a `Dictionary` instead of an `Array`.  For this example, I think `Array` is slightly simpler, but it doesn't really matter much.  With `Dictionary` you wouldn't need the extension, but adding a value requires using both a key and a value, whereas with `Array` I can just `append`.  `Dictionary` would be the way to go if you don't want to populate it with contributions for all months.

So next up, for a given month, we need to adjust combined contribution so that total annual contributions will be capped to the legal limit:

```swift
func calculateCombinedContribution(
    monthlyContribution        monthly    : Decimal,
    annualContributionLimit    limit      : Decimal,
    contributionsSoFarThisYear cummulative: Decimal) -> Decimal
{
    min(max(0, limit - cummulative), monthly)
}
```

Now all of that is used to compute a whole years worth of monthly contributions:

```swift
func computeMonthlyContributions(
    monthlyPay            : Decimal,
    contributionPercentage: Decimal,
    rothPercentage        : Decimal,
    contributionLimit     : Decimal) -> [MonthlyContributions]
{
    assert((0...100).contains(contributionPercentage))
    assert((0...100).contains(rothPercentage))
    assert(monthlyPay >= 0)
    assert(contributionLimit >= 0)
    
    var totalContributions  : Decimal = 0
    var monthlyContributions: [MonthlyContributions] = []
    monthlyContributions.reserveCapacity(ContributionMonth.count)

    let monthlyContribution = roundToNearestPenny(
        percentage: contributionPercentage,
        of: monthlyPay
    )
    
    for _ in ContributionMonth.allCases
    {
        let combinedAmount = calculateCombinedContribution(
            monthlyContribution       : monthlyContribution,
            annualContributionLimit   : contributionLimit,
            contributionsSoFarThisYear: totalContributions
        )
        
        let contribution = MonthlyContributions(
            combinedAmount: combinedAmount,
            rothPercentage: rothPercentage
        )

        monthlyContributions.append(contribution)
        totalContributions += contribution.total
    }
    
    return monthlyContributions
}
```

The assertions are just there to validate basic numeric assumptions, at least in `DEBUG` builds.  For each month we determine how much the combined contribution will be for that month, which takes into account whether the total contributions have reached the legal annual limit, then create a `MonthlyContributions` instance, which distributes the amount internally between `roth` and `traditional`, append it to the array, and update the total contributions.

Now we can call it with some values, and print out the calculated monthly contributions:

```swift
var monthlyPay            : Decimal = 15203.0
var personal401kLimit     : Decimal = 22500.0
var personal401kPercentage: Decimal = 10.0
var roth401kPercentage    : Decimal = 10.0

let monthlyContributions = computeMonthlyContributions(
    monthlyPay            : monthlyPay,
    contributionPercentage: personal401kPercentage,
    rothPercentage        : roth401kPercentage,
    contributionLimit     : personal401kLimit
)

for month in ContributionMonth.allCases
{
    let curContribution = monthlyContributions[month]
    print("Contribution for \(month)")
    print("    Roth       : $\(curContribution.roth)")
    print("    Traditional: $\(curContribution.traditional)")
    print()

}
```

This just uses the values you provide.  The output is:

```
Contribution for January
    Roth       : $152.03
    Traditional: $1368.27

Contribution for February
    Roth       : $152.03
    Traditional: $1368.27

Contribution for March
    Roth       : $152.03
    Traditional: $1368.27

Contribution for April
    Roth       : $152.03
    Traditional: $1368.27

Contribution for May
    Roth       : $152.03
    Traditional: $1368.27

Contribution for June
    Roth       : $152.03
    Traditional: $1368.27

Contribution for July
    Roth       : $152.03
    Traditional: $1368.27

Contribution for August
    Roth       : $152.03
    Traditional: $1368.27

Contribution for September
    Roth       : $152.03
    Traditional: $1368.27

Contribution for October
    Roth       : $152.03
    Traditional: $1368.27

Contribution for November
    Roth       : $152.03
    Traditional: $1368.27

Contribution for December
    Roth       : $152.03
    Traditional: $1368.27
```

As you can see the annual contribution limit isn't triggered by that `monthlyPay` value, so increasing it to `30000.0` does trigger it:

```
Contribution for January
    Roth       : $300
    Traditional: $2700

Contribution for February
    Roth       : $300
    Traditional: $2700

Contribution for March
    Roth       : $300
    Traditional: $2700

Contribution for April
    Roth       : $300
    Traditional: $2700

Contribution for May
    Roth       : $300
    Traditional: $2700

Contribution for June
    Roth       : $300
    Traditional: $2700

Contribution for July
    Roth       : $300
    Traditional: $2700

Contribution for August
    Roth       : $150
    Traditional: $1350

Contribution for September
    Roth       : $0
    Traditional: $0

Contribution for October
    Roth       : $0
    Traditional: $0

Contribution for November
    Roth       : $0
    Traditional: $0

Contribution for December
    Roth       : $0
    Traditional: $0
```

### Update

In comments, it became known that a year-to-date value needed to be stored in `MonthlyContributions`.  I proposed adding the year-to-date value as another stored property, and pass it's value in as another parameter to the `init` in the `extension`, but thinking on it more, that creates an API that's either not clear as to whether the value should include the current month's contributions or to make it clear would be unnecessarily wordy.  Super-long variable names are almost as bad overly short ones.  So the way I'd do it is to use the existing `MonthlyContributions` to create the one for the next month.

To do that I'd update `MonthlyContributions` like this:

```swift
struct MonthlyContributions
{
    var roth        : Decimal = 0
    var traditional : Decimal = 0
    var yearToDate  : Decimal = 0 // <-- ADDED THIS
}

extension MonthlyContributions
{
    var total: Decimal { roth + traditional }
    
    // CHANGED INITIALIZER TO INSTANCE METHOD
    func nextMonth(
        combinedAmount: Decimal, 
        rothPercentage: Decimal) -> Self
    {
        let roth = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: rothPercentage,
            of: combinedAmount
        )
        return Self(
            roth: roth, 
            traditional: combinedAmount - roth,
            yearToDate: combinedAmount + yearToDate
        )
    }
}
```

Then I'd change `computeMonthlyContributions` to create an empty (zeroed) `MonthlyContributions`, which is used in each iteration of the loop to create the `MonthlyContributions` for the next month.  The `totalContributions` variable is no longer needed because each month already has the total in it:

```swift
func computeMonthlyContributions(
    monthlyPay            : Decimal,
    contributionPercentage: Decimal,
    rothPercentage        : Decimal,
    contributionLimit     : Decimal) -> [MonthlyContributions]
{
    assert((0...100).contains(contributionPercentage))
    assert((0...100).contains(rothPercentage))
    assert(monthlyPay >= 0)
    assert(contributionLimit >= 0)

    // Start with a zeroed MonthlyContributions
    var contribution = MonthlyContributions()

    var monthlyContributions: [MonthlyContributions] = []
    monthlyContributions.reserveCapacity(ContributionMonth.count)

    let monthlyContribution = roundToNearestPenny(
        percentage: contributionPercentage,
        of: monthlyPay
    )

    for _ in ContributionMonth.allCases
    {
        // Apply limits to `contribution.yearToDate` 
        let combinedAmount = calculateCombinedContribution(
            monthlyContribution       : monthlyContribution,
            annualContributionLimit   : contributionLimit,
            contributionsSoFarThisYear: contribution.yearToDate
        )

        contribution = contribution.nextMonth(
            combinedAmount: combinedAmount,
            rothPercentage: rothPercentage
        )

        monthlyContributions.append(contribution)
    }

    return monthlyContributions
}
```

If you like you can now add the year-to-date contributions in the print loop:

```swift
for month in ContributionMonth.allCases
{
    let curContribution = monthlyContributions[month]
    print("    Roth        : $\(curContribution.roth)")
    print("    Traditional : $\(curContribution.traditional)")
    print("    Year-To-Date: $\(curContribution.yearToDate)")
    print()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!  I really appreciate the time and attention you put into your response!  There is a lot to digest here so I will likely be back to ask questions tomorrow and in days ahead.

Comment: Thank you again for all the detailed examples and explanations! As I attempt to move this into an Xcode project I am running into issues making the end values and calculations (print outs) applied into a ViewModel and View.  As I make the variables and "let monthlyContributions = computeMonthlyContributions(..." nested under a vm class (observable object) I receive errors for monthlyPay, contributionPercentage, RothPercentage, and contributionLimit needing property initializers.  Any advice on how you would structure your viewmodel and Table View to display this data?

Comment: I’d need to see the code in context, but if I understand you, it sounds as if you just need to provide an `init` for your view model, and initialize your properties there.  But in my mind, those should be part of your model, not view or view-model.  They probably eventually should be initialized from some persistent storage (`UserDefaults`, local or remote database, file, etc…).

Comment: Thanks! Back to the playground version... I would like to add one additional print out for each month: a running total (i.e. contributionsSoFarThisYear). Adding "print("Total: $\(curContribution.total)") only gives the monthly total, not the running cumulative total. Should I add a variable 'contributionsSoFarThisYear' to the extension MonthlyContributions?  Or is there a way to reference the contributionsSoFarThisYear within the function 'calculateCombinedContribution'?

Comment: You could add a `yearToDate` property to `MonthlyContributions` but you’d need it to be stored and set it in the initializer, but unless you need to store it, why not just keep a running total with a local variable and update it with each iteration of the print loop?

Comment: I believe I will need to store and initialize because the cumulative totals of each month will be used in the next task (determining when an employee can and cannot contribute to a 401a account (back-door Roth)).  I've given a more in-depth explanation and an unsuccessful example of playground code in my update to my original post (Update 1).

Comment: You'd need to add the `yearToDate` as a stored property in `MonthlyContributions` not as a computed variable, and it's not the same as `total`.  `total` is just the combined amount for that month of `roth` and `traditional`, but does not include any information about previous months.   You'd need to pass the `yearToDate` value in as another initializer argument.  In `computeMonthlyContributions` at the point where the `MonthlyContributions` instance is created, the `totalContributions` variable has the value of all contributions for that employee for the year BEFORE the current month.

Comment: You can move the line that updates `totalContributions` to the line just above creating the `MonthlyContributions`, so that it includes the current month, or you can leave it where it is, and let the initializer add `combinedContributions` to it internally.  Either way works.

Comment: I updated my answer with what I think is a better solution than passing the `yearToDate` to the initializer.  The idea is to use the previous month's `MonthlyContributions` to create the new one for the current month.  It can handle keeping the total for you.  That, I think, makes for a clearer API.

Comment: That was super helpful, thank you!! I have progressed the code to now include company direct contributions but am having trouble with the back-door-Roth 401a option.  I've started a new post and would love your insight. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75148567/playground-401k-calculator-unable-to-get-back-door-roth-function-to-work-prop