# Playground 401k Calculator: Unable to get "back-door-Roth" function to work properly. Seeking techniques to improve formulae

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm using Playground as a testing ground for code with the intention to transition in the near future to creating an iOS app.

**Background:**

In case the term "back-door-Roth" is unfamiliar, let me attempt to level the bubble.  If, in a given calendar year, an employee contributes to their 401k up to an amount totaling the IRS contribution limit (currently $22,500 in most cases), the employee typically is restricted by law to discontinue contributions.  However, an employer may offer a "back-door" option which would allow the employee to continue contributing beyond the IRS contribution limit. However those "above-the-limit" contributions are placed into a separate Roth account, often labeled a "401a" account.   This employee may continue to contribute to their 401a account throughout that calendar year so long as the sum total of his/her contributions and the company's contributions do not exceed the IRS combined contribution limit (currently $66,000 in most cases).

Thanks to Chip Jarred and other SO contributors, the below playground code is fully functional.  This code does not allow for 401a "back-door-Roth" contributions, but it is a solid foundation upon which I am building:

```swift
    import Foundation
    
    let pennyRoundingBehavior = NSDecimalNumberHandler(
        roundingMode: .bankers,
        scale: 2,
        raiseOnExactness: false,
        raiseOnOverflow: true,
        raiseOnUnderflow: true,
        raiseOnDivideByZero: true
    )
    
    func roundToNearestPenny(percentage: Decimal, of dollarAmount: Decimal) -> Decimal
    {
        assert((0...100).contains(percentage))
        
        let x = ((dollarAmount * percentage / 100) as NSDecimalNumber)
        return x.rounding(accordingToBehavior: pennyRoundingBehavior) as Decimal
    }
    
    enum ContributionMonth: Int, CaseIterable
    {
        case January, February, March, April, May, June,
             July, August, September, October, November, December
        
        static var count:Int  { allCases.count }
    }
    
    struct MonthlyContributions
    {
        var roth                : Decimal = 0
        var traditional         : Decimal = 0
        var rothCompany         : Decimal = 0
        var traditionalCompany  : Decimal = 0
        var yearToDate          : Decimal = 0
        var yearToDateAll       : Decimal = 0
    }
    
    extension MonthlyContributions
    {
        var total: Decimal { roth + traditional }
        var companyTotal: Decimal { rothCompany + traditionalCompany }
        
        func nextMonth(
            combinedAmount: Decimal,
            rothPercentage: Decimal,
            rothPercentageCompany: Decimal,
            combinedAmountCompany: Decimal
            ) -> Self
        {
            let roth = roundToNearestPenny(
                percentage: rothPercentage,
                of: combinedAmount
            )
            let rothCompany = roundToNearestPenny(
                percentage: rothPercentageCompany,
                of: combinedAmountCompany
            )
            return Self(
                roth: roth,
                traditional: combinedAmount - roth,
                rothCompany: rothCompany,
                traditionalCompany: combinedAmountCompany - rothCompany,
                yearToDate: combinedAmount + yearToDate,
                yearToDateAll: combinedAmount + combinedAmountCompany + yearToDateAll
            )
        }
    }
    
    extension Array where Element == MonthlyContributions {
        subscript (index: ContributionMonth) -> Element { self[index.rawValue] }
    }
    
    func calculatePersCombinedContribution(
        monthlyContribution        monthly    : Decimal,
        annualContributionLimit    limit      : Decimal,
        contributionsSoFarThisYear cummulative: Decimal) -> Decimal
    {
        min(max(0, limit - cummulative), monthly)
    }
    func calculateAllCombinedContribution(
        monthlyContribution             monthly : Decimal,
        annualCombinedContributionLimit limit   : Decimal,
        allContributionsSoFarThisYear   cummulative: Decimal) -> Decimal
    {
        min(max(0, limit - cummulative), monthly)
    }
    
    func computeMonthlyContributions(
        monthlyPay            : Decimal,
        contributionPercentage: Decimal,
        companyContributionPercentage: Decimal,
        rothPercentage        : Decimal,
        contributionLimit     : Decimal,
        combinedContributionLimit: Decimal) -> [MonthlyContributions]
    {
        assert((0...100).contains(contributionPercentage))
        assert((0...100).contains(rothPercentage))
        assert(monthlyPay >= 0)
        assert(contributionLimit >= 0)
    
        var contribution = MonthlyContributions()
    
        var monthlyContributions: [MonthlyContributions] = []
        monthlyContributions.reserveCapacity(ContributionMonth.count)
    
        let monthlyContribution = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: contributionPercentage,
            of: monthlyPay
        )
        let monthlyCompanyContribution = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: companyContributionPercentage,
            of: monthlyPay
        )
        for _ in ContributionMonth.allCases
        {
            let combinedPersAmount = calculatePersCombinedContribution(
                monthlyContribution       : monthlyContribution,
                annualContributionLimit   : contributionLimit,
                contributionsSoFarThisYear: contribution.yearToDate
            )
            let combinedAllAmount = calculateAllCombinedContribution(
                monthlyContribution             : monthlyCompanyContribution,
                annualCombinedContributionLimit : combinedContributionLimit,
                allContributionsSoFarThisYear   : contribution.yearToDateAll
            )
            contribution = contribution.nextMonth(
                combinedAmount: combinedPersAmount,
                rothPercentage: rothPercentage,
                rothPercentageCompany: rothPercentage,
                combinedAmountCompany: combinedAllAmount
            )
    
            monthlyContributions.append(contribution)
        }
    
        return monthlyContributions
    }
    
    var monthlyPay            : Decimal = 12758.0
    var personal401kLimit     : Decimal = 22500.0
    var personal401kPercentage: Decimal = 100.0
    var companyContributionPercentage: Decimal = 16.0
    var roth401kPercentage    : Decimal = 10.0
    var combinedContributionLimit : Decimal = 66000.0
    
    let monthlyContributions = computeMonthlyContributions(
        monthlyPay            : monthlyPay,
        contributionPercentage: personal401kPercentage,
        companyContributionPercentage : companyContributionPercentage,
        rothPercentage        : roth401kPercentage,
        contributionLimit     : personal401kLimit,
        combinedContributionLimit : combinedContributionLimit
    )
    
    for month in ContributionMonth.allCases
    {
        let curContribution = monthlyContributions[month]
        print("Contribution for \(month)")
        print("    Traditional : $\(curContribution.traditional)")
        print("    Roth        : $\(curContribution.roth)")
        print("    Year-To-Date: $\(curContribution.yearToDate)")
        print("    Company Trad: $\(curContribution.traditionalCompany)")
        print("    Company Roth: $\(curContribution.rothCompany)")
        print("    Combined Year-To-Date: $\(curContribution.yearToDateAll)")
        print()
    }
```

The output:

```
    Contribution for January
        Traditional : $11482.2
        Roth        : $1275.8
        Year-To-Date: $12758
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $14799.28
    
    Contribution for February
        Traditional : $8767.8
        Roth        : $974.2
        Year-To-Date: $22500
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $26582.56
    
    Contribution for March
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Year-To-Date: $22500
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $28623.84
    
    Contribution for April
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Year-To-Date: $22500
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $30665.12
    
    Contribution for May
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Year-To-Date: $22500
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $32706.4
    
    Contribution for June
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Year-To-Date: $22500
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $34747.68
    
    Contribution for July
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Year-To-Date: $22500
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $36788.96
    
    Contribution for August
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Year-To-Date: $22500
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $38830.24
    
    Contribution for September
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Year-To-Date: $22500
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $40871.52
    
    Contribution for October
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Year-To-Date: $22500
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $42912.8
    
    Contribution for November
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Year-To-Date: $22500
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $44954.08
    
    Contribution for December
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Year-To-Date: $22500
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $46995.36
```

**Now on to improve this code to include 401a contributions...**

This is a snipped image of a working excel product that contains the functionality I wish to translate into Playground:

[image: spreadsheet snip]

I have updated the above "foundation" code in an attempt to incorporate 401a contributions. You'll see that 401a contributions in January and February look correct (matches the excel spreadsheet) but March and on are not correct (do not match the excel spreadsheet):

```swift
    import Foundation
    
    let pennyRoundingBehavior = NSDecimalNumberHandler(
        roundingMode: .bankers,
        scale: 2,
        raiseOnExactness: false,
        raiseOnOverflow: true,
        raiseOnUnderflow: true,
        raiseOnDivideByZero: true
    )
    
    func roundToNearestPenny(percentage: Decimal, of dollarAmount: Decimal) -> Decimal
    {
        assert((0...100).contains(percentage))
        
        let x = ((dollarAmount * percentage / 100) as NSDecimalNumber)
        return x.rounding(accordingToBehavior: pennyRoundingBehavior) as Decimal
    }
    
    enum ContributionMonth: Int, CaseIterable
    {
        case January, February, March, April, May, June,
             July, August, September, October, November, December
        
        static var count:Int  { allCases.count }
    }
    
    struct MonthlyContributions
    {
        var roth                : Decimal = 0
        var traditional         : Decimal = 0
        var pers401a            : Decimal = 0
        var rothCompany         : Decimal = 0
        var traditionalCompany  : Decimal = 0
        var yearToDate          : Decimal = 0
        var yearToDateAll       : Decimal = 0
    }
    
    extension MonthlyContributions
    {
        var total: Decimal { roth + traditional }
        var companyTotal: Decimal { rothCompany + traditionalCompany }
        
        func nextMonth(
            combinedAmount: Decimal,
            rothPercentage: Decimal,
            rothPercentageCompany: Decimal,
            combinedAmountCompany: Decimal
            ) -> Self
        {
            let roth = roundToNearestPenny(
                percentage: rothPercentage,
                of: combinedAmount
            )
            let rothCompany = roundToNearestPenny(
                percentage: rothPercentageCompany,
                of: combinedAmountCompany
            )
            return Self(
                roth: roth,
                traditional: combinedAmount - roth,
                pers401a: combinedAmount < total ? total - combinedAmount : 0,
                rothCompany: rothCompany,
                traditionalCompany: combinedAmountCompany - rothCompany,
                yearToDate: combinedAmount + pers401a + yearToDate,
                yearToDateAll: combinedAmount + combinedAmountCompany + yearToDateAll
            )
        }
    }
    
    extension Array where Element == MonthlyContributions {
        subscript (index: ContributionMonth) -> Element { self[index.rawValue] }
    }
    
    func calculatePersCombinedContribution(
        monthlyContribution        monthly      : Decimal,
        annualContributionLimit    limit        : Decimal,
        contributionsSoFarThisYear cummulative  : Decimal) -> Decimal
    {
        min(max(0, limit - cummulative), monthly)
    }
    func calculate401aContribution(
        monthlyContribution         monthly     : Decimal,
        combinedContributionLimit    limit        : Decimal,
        contributionsSoFarThisYear cummulative  : Decimal) -> Decimal
    {
        min(max(0, limit - cummulative), monthly)
    }
    func calculateAllCombinedContribution(
        monthlyContribution             monthly : Decimal,
        annualCombinedContributionLimit limit   : Decimal,
        allContributionsSoFarThisYear   cummulative: Decimal) -> Decimal
    {
        min(max(0, limit - cummulative), monthly)
    }
    
    func computeMonthlyContributions(
        monthlyPay            : Decimal,
        contributionPercentage: Decimal,
        companyContributionPercentage: Decimal,
        rothPercentage        : Decimal,
        contributionLimit     : Decimal,
        combinedContributionLimit: Decimal) -> [MonthlyContributions]
    {
        assert((0...100).contains(contributionPercentage))
        assert((0...100).contains(rothPercentage))
        assert(monthlyPay >= 0)
        assert(contributionLimit >= 0)
    
        var contribution = MonthlyContributions()
    
        var monthlyContributions: [MonthlyContributions] = []
        monthlyContributions.reserveCapacity(ContributionMonth.count)
    
        let monthlyContribution = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: contributionPercentage,
            of: monthlyPay
        )
        let monthlyCompanyContribution = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: companyContributionPercentage,
            of: monthlyPay
        )
        for _ in ContributionMonth.allCases
        {
            let combinedPersAmount = calculatePersCombinedContribution(
                monthlyContribution       : monthlyContribution,
                annualContributionLimit   : contributionLimit,
                contributionsSoFarThisYear: contribution.yearToDate
            )
            let pers401Amount = calculate401aContribution(
                monthlyContribution: monthlyContribution,
                combinedContributionLimit: combinedContributionLimit,
                contributionsSoFarThisYear: contribution.yearToDateAll
            )
            let combinedAllAmount = calculateAllCombinedContribution(
                monthlyContribution             : monthlyCompanyContribution,
                annualCombinedContributionLimit : combinedContributionLimit,
                allContributionsSoFarThisYear   : contribution.yearToDateAll
            )
            contribution = contribution.nextMonth(
                combinedAmount: combinedPersAmount,
                rothPercentage: rothPercentage,
                rothPercentageCompany: rothPercentage,
                combinedAmountCompany: combinedAllAmount
            )
    
            monthlyContributions.append(contribution)
        }
    
        return monthlyContributions
    }
    
    var monthlyPay            : Decimal = 12758.0
    var personal401kLimit     : Decimal = 22500.0
    var personal401kPercentage: Decimal = 100.0
    var companyContributionPercentage: Decimal = 16.0
    var roth401kPercentage    : Decimal = 10.0
    var combinedContributionLimit : Decimal = 66000.0
    
    let monthlyContributions = computeMonthlyContributions(
        monthlyPay            : monthlyPay,
        contributionPercentage: personal401kPercentage,
        companyContributionPercentage : companyContributionPercentage,
        rothPercentage        : roth401kPercentage,
        contributionLimit     : personal401kLimit,
        combinedContributionLimit : combinedContributionLimit
    )
    
    for month in ContributionMonth.allCases
    {
        let curContribution = monthlyContributions[month]
        print("Contribution for \(month)")
        print("    Traditional : $\(curContribution.traditional)")
        print("    Roth        : $\(curContribution.roth)")
        print("    Pers 401a   : $\(curContribution.pers401a)")
    //    print("    Pers Year-To-Date: $\(curContribution.yearToDate)")
        print("    Company Trad: $\(curContribution.traditionalCompany)")
        print("    Company Roth: $\(curContribution.rothCompany)")
        print("    Combined Year-To-Date: $\(curContribution.yearToDateAll)")
        print()
    }
```

The output:

```
    Contribution for January
        Traditional : $11482.2
        Roth        : $1275.8
        Pers 401a   : $0
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $14799.28
    
    Contribution for February
        Traditional : $8767.8
        Roth        : $974.2
        Pers 401a   : $3016
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $26582.56
    
    Contribution for March
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Pers 401a   : $9742
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $28623.84
    
    Contribution for April
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Pers 401a   : $0
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $30665.12
    
    Contribution for May
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Pers 401a   : $0
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $32706.4
    
    Contribution for June
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Pers 401a   : $0
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $34747.68
    
    Contribution for July
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Pers 401a   : $0
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $36788.96
    
    ...
    Contribution for December
        Traditional : $0
        Roth        : $0
        Pers 401a   : $0
        Company Trad: $1837.15
        Company Roth: $204.13
        Combined Year-To-Date: $46995.36
```

The goal is for the printouts for "Pers 401a" and "Combined Year-To-Date" monthly values to reflect the excel spreadsheet.

**UPDATE**

I created an additional year-to-date totals with the purpose to correctly limit the 401a, but then realized that the conditionals which define 401a only reference two types of year-to-date totals: 1) the sum of the previous month personal Roth and Traditional contributions &
2) the sum of the previous month personal, company and 401a contributions.
Consequently, I believe I only need "yearToDate" and "yearToDateAll" variables so long as the "yearToDateAll" includes previous month 401a contributions.

I have outlined the conditionals which define each month's 401a contributions in comments below and applied the comments into code, but the results are messy and inaccurate.

```swift
import Foundation

let pennyRoundingBehavior = NSDecimalNumberHandler(
    roundingMode: .bankers,
    scale: 2,
    raiseOnExactness: false,
    raiseOnOverflow: true,
    raiseOnUnderflow: true,
    raiseOnDivideByZero: true
)

func roundToNearestPenny(percentage: Decimal, of dollarAmount: Decimal) -> Decimal
{
    assert((0...100).contains(percentage))
    
    let x = ((dollarAmount * percentage / 100) as NSDecimalNumber)
    return x.rounding(accordingToBehavior: pennyRoundingBehavior) as Decimal
}

enum ContributionMonth: Int, CaseIterable
{
    case January, February, March, April, May, June,
         July, August, September, October, November, December
    
    static var count:Int  { allCases.count }
}

struct MonthlyContributions
{
    var roth                : Decimal = 0
    var traditional         : Decimal = 0
    var rothCompany         : Decimal = 0
    var traditionalCompany  : Decimal = 0
    var yearToDate          : Decimal = 0
    var yearToDateAll       : Decimal = 0
    var pers401a            : Decimal = 0
}

extension MonthlyContributions
{
    var total: Decimal { roth + traditional }
    var companyTotal: Decimal { rothCompany + traditionalCompany }
    
    func nextMonth(
        combinedAmount: Decimal,
        rothPercentage: Decimal,
        rothPercentageCompany: Decimal,
        combinedAmountCompany: Decimal
        ) -> Self
    {
        let roth = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: rothPercentage,
            of: combinedAmount
        )
        let rothCompany = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: rothPercentageCompany,
            of: combinedAmountCompany
        )
        return Self(
            roth: roth,
            traditional: combinedAmount - roth,
            rothCompany: rothCompany,
            traditionalCompany: combinedAmountCompany - rothCompany,
            yearToDate: combinedAmount + yearToDate,
            yearToDateAll: combinedAmount + pers401a + combinedAmountCompany + yearToDateAll,
            /*
             pers401a conditionals:
             1. If the sum of the previous month's running total of 
                personal and company contributions + this month's 
                personal contributions is < personal401klimit 
                ($22,500), then pers401a = 0, otherwise...
             2. If the sum of the previous month's running total of 
                personal and company contributions >= the 
                combined401klimit ($66,500), then pers401a = 0, 
                otherwise...
             3. If the sum of the previous month's running total of 
                personal and company contributions + this month's 
                personal roth and traditional contributions < the 
                combined401klimit ($66,500), then...
                    a. if ((this month's personal roth + 
                       traditional contributions) - (sum of all                
                       previous month's peresonal roth & traditional
                       contributions)) = 0, then pers401a = 0, otherwise...
                    b. pers401a = (this month's personal roth + traditional
                       contributions) - (sum of all previous month's 
                       peresonal roth & traditional contributions), otherwise...
             4. pers401a = combined401klimit - the sum of the previous 
                month's running total of personal and company  contributions.
            */
            pers401a:
                yearToDateAll + total < personal401kLimit ? 0 :
                yearToDateAll >= combinedContributionLimit ? 0 :
                yearToDateAll + total < combinedContributionLimit ?
                    (total - yearToDate) == 0 ? 0 :
                    (total - yearToDate) :
                combinedContributionLimit - yearToDateAll
        )
    }
}

extension Array where Element == MonthlyContributions {
    subscript (index: ContributionMonth) -> Element { self[index.rawValue] }
}

func calculateAllCombinedContribution(
    monthlyContribution          monthly    : Decimal,
    annualContributionLimit      limit      : Decimal,
    contributionsSoFarThisYear   cummulative: Decimal) -> Decimal
{
    min(max(0, limit - cummulative), monthly)
}

func computeMonthlyContributions(
    monthlyPay                      : Decimal,
    contributionPercentage          : Decimal,
    companyContributionPercentage   : Decimal,
    rothPercentage                  : Decimal,
    contributionLimit               : Decimal,
    combinedContributionLimit       : Decimal) -> [MonthlyContributions]
{
    assert((0...100).contains(contributionPercentage))
    assert((0...100).contains(rothPercentage))
    assert(monthlyPay >= 0)
    assert(contributionLimit >= 0)

    var contribution = MonthlyContributions()

    var monthlyContributions: [MonthlyContributions] = []
    monthlyContributions.reserveCapacity(ContributionMonth.count)

    let monthlyContribution = roundToNearestPenny(
        percentage: contributionPercentage,
        of: monthlyPay
    )
    let monthlyCompanyContribution = roundToNearestPenny(
        percentage: companyContributionPercentage,
        of: monthlyPay
    )
    for _ in ContributionMonth.allCases
    {
        let combinedPersAmount = calculateAllCombinedContribution(
            monthlyContribution       : monthlyContribution,
            annualContributionLimit   : contributionLimit,
            contributionsSoFarThisYear: contribution.yearToDate
        )
        let pers401Amount = calculateAllCombinedContribution(
            monthlyContribution         : monthlyContribution,
            annualContributionLimit     : combinedContributionLimit,
            //incorporate new yearToDate401a
            contributionsSoFarThisYear  : contribution.yearToDateAll
        )
        let combinedAllAmount = calculateAllCombinedContribution(
            monthlyContribution         : monthlyCompanyContribution,
            annualContributionLimit     : combinedContributionLimit,
            contributionsSoFarThisYear  : contribution.yearToDateAll
        )
        contribution = contribution.nextMonth(
            combinedAmount: combinedPersAmount,
            rothPercentage: rothPercentage,
            rothPercentageCompany: rothPercentage,
            combinedAmountCompany: combinedAllAmount
        )

        monthlyContributions.append(contribution)
    }

    return monthlyContributions
}

var monthlyPay            : Decimal = 12758.0
var personal401kLimit     : Decimal = 22500.0
var personal401kPercentage: Decimal = 100.0
var companyContributionPercentage: Decimal = 16.0
var roth401kPercentage    : Decimal = 10.0
var combinedContributionLimit : Decimal = 66000.0

let monthlyContributions = computeMonthlyContributions(
    monthlyPay            : monthlyPay,
    contributionPercentage: personal401kPercentage,
    companyContributionPercentage : companyContributionPercentage,
    rothPercentage        : roth401kPercentage,
    contributionLimit     : personal401kLimit,
    combinedContributionLimit : combinedContributionLimit
)

for month in ContributionMonth.allCases
{
    let curContribution = monthlyContributions[month]
    print("Contribution for \(month)")
    print("    Traditional : $\(curContribution.traditional)")
    print("    Roth        : $\(curContribution.roth)")
    print("    Pers 401a   : $\(curContribution.pers401a)")
//    print("    Pers Year-To-Date: $\(curContribution.yearToDate)")
    print("    Company Trad: $\(curContribution.traditionalCompany)")
    print("    Company Roth: $\(curContribution.rothCompany)")
    print("    Combined Year-To-Date: $\(curContribution.yearToDateAll)")
    print()
}
```

The output:

```
Contribution for January
    Traditional : $11482.2
    Roth        : $1275.8
    Pers 401a   : $0
    Company Trad: $1837.15
    Company Roth: $204.13
    Combined Year-To-Date: $14799.28

Contribution for February
    Traditional : $8767.8
    Roth        : $974.2
    Pers 401a   : $0
    Company Trad: $1837.15
    Company Roth: $204.13
    Combined Year-To-Date: $26582.56

Contribution for March
    Traditional : $0
    Roth        : $0
    Pers 401a   : $-12758
    Company Trad: $1837.15
    Company Roth: $204.13
    Combined Year-To-Date: $28623.84

Contribution for April
    Traditional : $0
    Roth        : $0
    Pers 401a   : $-22500
    Company Trad: $1837.15
    Company Roth: $204.13
    Combined Year-To-Date: $17907.12

Contribution for May
    Traditional : $0
    Roth        : $0
    Pers 401a   : $0
    Company Trad: $1837.15
    Company Roth: $204.13
    Combined Year-To-Date: $-2551.6


...
```

Comment: It's hard to tell right away where's the issue. I'd suggest to break down the calculations into smaller steps and make sure that every step issues a correct output. Alternatively, move this code from the playground to a sample app, then you'll be able to use the debugger to execute the code line by line.

Comment: So the code to compute 401k contributions works but the 401a contributions don't.  So stop and think how you'd compute the them manually.  Starting by thinking through what is your starting point for the 401a contribution.  You have the total of how much they've elected to contribute for the current month, and you have have how much they've actually contributed after how much the 401k annual limit is applied.  So given that information how much do they have available for 401a.  Then you have a second annual limit to apply (which includes company matching contributions).

Comment: It seems to me that you'll need additional year-to-date totals to correctly limit the 401a.  Write down the manual steps in comments, and then implement the code for it.  Also re-think code from previous evolution:  For example, right now`calculatePersCombinedContribution`, `calculate401aContribution` and `calculateAllCombinedContribution ` have identical implementations.  Maybe combine them into a more general `limitContributions` function, or perhaps to an even more general `clamp` function.  Sometimes duplicated code makes sense, but much more often, it should be combined (DRY principle).

Comment: Not something to worry about at this early stage, but the code assumes that the employee (and company) contribution percentages are fixed for the whole year.  In reality employees can alter the percentage of their pay they want to contribute (I think quarterly), which will require applying different percentages for different months.  Fix the problem at hand first, but if you're going to use it for real eventually, you'll need to think how you're going to do that.

Comment: @Chip Jarred As always, thank you for your helpful insight! I have applied the DRY principle to the "calculate...Contribution" functions.  And I have written the manual steps in comments and implemented code for it.  The result is so inaccurate I feel like I've regressed/taken steps backward. See the update to my original post.  I ran out of space (exceeded maximum characters for the original post) so I trimmed some code from the outputs.  If you agree that this post and my previous post show "research effort; it is useful and clear" would you please so indicate?

Comment: I meant for the manual steps in comments to be a guide for you in implementing it.  As a matter of personal taste (others may reasonably dispute this), I find lots of computation being done in-place for arguments, such as the nested ternary expressions, hard to read.  I think it would be clearer compute them in named variables before calling designated initializer (the call to `Self(...)`).   Ternaries are perfectly readable for short conditional expressions, but when you start nesting them it's clearer to just use `if` statements, assigning to a variable which you then pass as an argument.

Comment: As for showing research effort, if someone had marked the questions as needing it, those markings seem to have been removed.  The question could be clearer.  Unless it's relevant for the question, or to important answers that have been given, you don't need to show every evolution of the code.  Showing your current code with output as appropriate with an explicit question about it is sufficient.   And of course, say what you expected the result to be and how the actual result isn't that.   That said it's better than a lot of SO questions.

Comment: Following up, you did show what you expected the output to be and the actual result.  I just realized that my comment might be taken to suggest that you hadn't.  For improvement, I would say, remember people on SO are freely using their valuable time to help others, so don't make them work just to see where the output differs from expectations.  In this case, you could have marked up the output to highlight where it differs.  As it is, the visual separation between the two requires work to see it.  The table of expected values is good as an addition though, for once someone digs into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your last version of the code as my starting point.

I think that you are trying to do too much in the `nextMonth()` method. You compute the 401k contribution amount before calling it.  I would suggest computing the 401a contribution the same way.  So `nextMonth()` can be simplified.

```swift
extension MonthlyContributions
{
    var total: Decimal { roth + traditional }
    var companyTotal: Decimal { rothCompany + traditionalCompany }
    
    func nextMonth(
        combinedAmount: Decimal,
        rothPercentage: Decimal,
        rothPercentageCompany: Decimal,
        combinedAmountCompany: Decimal,
        pers401a: Decimal) -> Self
    {
        let roth = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: rothPercentage,
            of: combinedAmount
        )
        let rothCompany = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: rothPercentageCompany,
            of: combinedAmountCompany
        )
        return Self(
            roth: roth,
            traditional: combinedAmount - roth,
            rothCompany: rothCompany,
            traditionalCompany: combinedAmountCompany - rothCompany,
            yearToDate: combinedAmount + yearToDate,
            yearToDateAll: combinedAmount + pers401a + combinedAmountCompany + yearToDateAll,
            pers401a: pers401a
        )
    }
}
```

In `computeMonthlyContributions` there are a couple of problems.

The first is that you are computing the pre-limit company contribution outside the loop from constant pre-limit employee contributions.  I think you were just following the same pattern for company contributions as for employee contributions, but that's not quite right.  The amount the company contributes should be computed based on the employee's actual contribution after the employee limit has been applied, and that's only available in the loop body.

Another issue is that when applying the annual limit to the 401a contribution, both personal *and* company contributions for the current month have to be included in the year-to-date total.

I renamed the function to limit contributions to be a little clearer - or at least I hope it's clearer:

```swift
func clampContribution(
    _                   current    : Decimal,
    whenCumulativeValue cummulative: Decimal,
    exceeds             limit      : Decimal) -> Decimal
{
    min(max(0, limit - cummulative), current)
}
```

Note that I swapped the order of the last two parameters compared to the previous version.  That was to make it read more like an English sentence.  It does exactly the same thing as the previous version, so it's just a matter of naming.  If you keep the previous one, be aware that the code below uses this new version, so you'll need to appropriately swap the last two parameters where I call `clampContributions`.

Then made the changes I described to `computeMonthlyContributions`:

```swift
func computeMonthlyContributions(
    monthlyPay                      : Decimal,
    contributionPercentage          : Decimal,
    companyContributionPercentage   : Decimal,
    rothPercentage                  : Decimal,
    contributionLimit               : Decimal,
    combinedContributionLimit       : Decimal) -> [MonthlyContributions]
{
    assert((0...100).contains(contributionPercentage))
    assert((0...100).contains(rothPercentage))
    assert(monthlyPay >= 0)
    assert(contributionLimit >= 0)

    var contribution = MonthlyContributions()

    var monthlyContributions: [MonthlyContributions] = []
    monthlyContributions.reserveCapacity(ContributionMonth.count)

    let monthlyContribution = roundToNearestPenny(
        percentage: contributionPercentage,
        of: monthlyPay
    )
    for _ in ContributionMonth.allCases
    {
        let combinedPersAmount = clampContribution(
            monthlyContribution,
            whenCumulativeValue: contribution.yearToDate,
            exceeds: contributionLimit
        )

        // ADDED THIS
        // Include personal contribution in overall YTD 401k total so it
        // will limit company contribution.
        var newYearToDateAll = contribution.yearToDateAll + combinedPersAmount

        // MOVED THIS FROM OUTSIDE THE LOOP TO HERE
        // Compute company contribution based on employee's actual contribution
        let monthlyCompanyContribution = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: companyContributionPercentage,
            of: combinedPersAmount // <-- CHANGED THIS
        )

        // Limit company contribution based on overall YTD 401k total,
        // which includes the employee's contribution for this month.
        let companyContribution = clampContribution(
            monthlyCompanyContribution,
            whenCumulativeValue: newYearToDateAll, // <-- CHANGED THIS
            exceeds: combinedContributionLimit
        )
        
        // ADDED THIS
        // Include company contribution in overall YTD 401k total so it 
        // will limit 401a contributions.
        newYearToDateAll += companyContribution
        
        // ADDED THIS
        // Compute amount of personal contribution available for 401a
        let preLimit401aAmount = monthlyContribution - combinedPersAmount;

        // Limit the 401a contribution based on overall YTD 401k total, 
        // which now includes this month's employee and company contributions.
        let pers401Amount = clampContribution(
            preLimit401aAmount,  // <-- CHANGED THIS
            whenCumulativeValue: newYearToDateAll, // <-- CHANGED THIS
            exceeds: combinedContributionLimit
        )

        contribution = contribution.nextMonth(
            combinedAmount: combinedPersAmount,
            rothPercentage: rothPercentage,
            rothPercentageCompany: rothPercentage,
            combinedAmountCompany: companyContribution,
            pers401a: pers401Amount
        )
        
        assert(contribution.yearToDate <= contributionLimit)
        assert(contribution.yearToDateAll <= combinedContributionLimit)

        monthlyContributions.append(contribution)
    }

    return monthlyContributions
}
```

I also added sanity checks (`assert` calls) to verify that the limits aren't exceeded after the new `MonthlyContributions` instance is created.

This is the output:

```
Contribution for January
    Traditional : $11482.2
    Roth        : $1275.8
    Pers 401a   : $0
    Company Trad: $1837.15
    Company Roth: $204.13
    Combined Year-To-Date: $14799.28

Contribution for February
    Traditional : $8767.8
    Roth        : $974.2
    Pers 401a   : $3016
    Company Trad: $1402.85
    Company Roth: $155.87
    Combined Year-To-Date: $29116

Contribution for March
    Traditional : $0
    Roth        : $0
    Pers 401a   : $12758
    Company Trad: $0
    Company Roth: $0
    Combined Year-To-Date: $41874

Contribution for April
    Traditional : $0
    Roth        : $0
    Pers 401a   : $12758
    Company Trad: $0
    Company Roth: $0
    Combined Year-To-Date: $54632

Contribution for May
    Traditional : $0
    Roth        : $0
    Pers 401a   : $11368
    Company Trad: $0
    Company Roth: $0
    Combined Year-To-Date: $66000

Contribution for June
    Traditional : $0
    Roth        : $0
    Pers 401a   : $0
    Company Trad: $0
    Company Roth: $0
    Combined Year-To-Date: $66000

Contribution for July
    Traditional : $0
    Roth        : $0
    Pers 401a   : $0
    Company Trad: $0
    Company Roth: $0
    Combined Year-To-Date: $66000

Contribution for August
    Traditional : $0
    Roth        : $0
    Pers 401a   : $0
    Company Trad: $0
    Company Roth: $0
    Combined Year-To-Date: $66000

Contribution for September
    Traditional : $0
    Roth        : $0
    Pers 401a   : $0
    Company Trad: $0
    Company Roth: $0
    Combined Year-To-Date: $66000

Contribution for October
    Traditional : $0
    Roth        : $0
    Pers 401a   : $0
    Company Trad: $0
    Company Roth: $0
    Combined Year-To-Date: $66000

Contribution for November
    Traditional : $0
    Roth        : $0
    Pers 401a   : $0
    Company Trad: $0
    Company Roth: $0
    Combined Year-To-Date: $66000

Contribution for December
    Traditional : $0
    Roth        : $0
    Pers 401a   : $0
    Company Trad: $0
    Company Roth: $0
    Combined Year-To-Date: $66000
```

### Refactored Version

With the code working, it might be time to think how it would be used in an actual app.  There are several things that it just doesn't handle.  Employees can periodically change their contribution percentages.  Their pay can change, hopefully for the better!

Originally, I said that you were doing too much in `nextMonth`.  It seemed to be causing confusion about how to do the calculations, especially since part of the calculations were done before calling `nextMonth` and part were done inside of `nextMonth`.  I felt it was important to keep `nextMonth` simple, so all it did was split 401k contributions between Roth and traditional 401k.

But now that it's working, given that it will need to be more flexible to handle the cases I mentioned above, it would be better to have all of the contribution code in one place.  That simplifies the code that calls it, as well as encodes the knowledge of how to do the computation in one place.  These changes in code structure are a normal part of programming.  When you're just trying to get something work in the basic case, you might need it structured one way to help you think through it, but then once you have that working, and start thinking of its broader use, you might realize you need it structured differently.

The problem with putting all that contribution code in `nextMonth` is that you need to pass in all the percentages and annual limits, and long parameter lists kind of suck.  One solution is to create a "parameter pack" that contains all the parameter data.  It's just a `struct` that you pass as one parameter, instead passing a lot of individual parameters.

```swift
struct ContributionSplitInfo
{
    // These are static because they are shared among all employees.
    static let personal401kLimit        : Decimal = 22500.0
    static let combined401kAnnualLimit  : Decimal = 66000.0
    static let companyMatchingPercentage: Decimal = 16.0
    
    /*
     These are provided as convenience, and because if for some reason they
     need to be individualized for each employee, that can be done without
     affecting the code that uses it.  For example, tax law could change limits,
     but existing employees might be grandfathered with the old limits.
     Similarly the company might change its matching rate for new hires, but
     not for new hires, or might have increasing matching with years of service.
     */
    var personal401kAnnualLimit  : Decimal { Self.personal401kLimit }
    var combined401kAnnualLimit  : Decimal { Self.combined401kAnnualLimit }
    var companyMatchingPercentage: Decimal { Self.companyMatchingPercentage }
    
    // These are stored instance properties because each employee can set them
    // differently
    var personal401kPercentage   : Decimal
    var rothPercentage           : Decimal
}
```

Note that it does *not* include the monthly pay.  We'll only be using one instance for now, but you could create one for each employee, or even have multiple ones for each employee as they make changes to their percentages throughout the year.

`nextMonth` needs changing to use it.  I've added in all of the code to compute the current month's contributions, and extracted some of the individual computations into `private` methods, in hopes of making it more self-documenting.  I did include one doc comment for one of the private methods, because the way I implemented it, it updates a year-to-date `inout` parameter, and I wanted to be clear what is expected on entry and what it will be on return.

The following code goes in the `MonthlyContributions` `extension`.

```swift
    func nextMonth(pay: Decimal, using splitInfo: ContributionSplitInfo) -> Self
    {
        assert((0...100).contains(splitInfo.personal401kPercentage))
        assert((0...100).contains(splitInfo.companyMatchingPercentage))
        assert((0...100).contains(splitInfo.rothPercentage))
        assert(splitInfo.personal401kAnnualLimit >= 0)
        assert(splitInfo.combined401kAnnualLimit >= 0)
        assert(pay >= 0)


        let (personal401kContribution, prelimit401aContribution) =
            self.personal401kContribution(fromPay: pay, using: splitInfo)
        
        var combinedYearToDateContributions = yearToDateAll

        let company401kContribution = self.company401kContribution(
            fromPersonalContribution: personal401kContribution,
            andCombinedYearToDateContributions: &combinedYearToDateContributions,
            using: splitInfo
        )

        let personal401aContribution = clampContribution(
            prelimit401aContribution,
            whenCumulativeValue: combinedYearToDateContributions,
            exceeds: splitInfo.combined401kAnnualLimit
        )
        
        combinedYearToDateContributions += personal401aContribution
        
        let (personalTraditional, personalRoth) = split401kContribution(
            contribution: personal401kContribution,
            rothPercentage: splitInfo.rothPercentage
        )
        
        let (companyTraditional, companyRoth) = split401kContribution(
            contribution: company401kContribution,
            rothPercentage: splitInfo.rothPercentage
        )
        
        let contributions = Self(
            roth              : personalRoth,
            traditional       : personalTraditional,
            rothCompany       : companyRoth,
            traditionalCompany: companyTraditional,
            yearToDate        : yearToDate + personal401kContribution,
            yearToDateAll     : combinedYearToDateContributions,
            pers401a          : personal401aContribution
        )
        
        assert(contributions.yearToDate <= splitInfo.personal401kAnnualLimit)
        assert(contributions.yearToDateAll <= splitInfo.combined401kAnnualLimit)

        return contributions
    }
    
    private func split401kContribution(
        contribution: Decimal,
        rothPercentage: Decimal) -> (traditional: Decimal, roth: Decimal)
    {
        let roth = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: rothPercentage,
            of: contribution
        )
        
        return (contribution - roth, roth)
    }
    
    private func personal401kContribution(
        fromPay pay: Decimal,
        using splitInfo: ContributionSplitInfo)
        -> (contribution: Decimal, unused: Decimal)
    {
        let prelimitContribution = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: splitInfo.personal401kPercentage,
            of: pay
        )
        let actualContribution = clampContribution(
            prelimitContribution,
            whenCumulativeValue: yearToDate,
            exceeds: splitInfo.personal401kAnnualLimit
        )
        
        return (actualContribution, prelimitContribution - actualContribution)
    }
    
    /**
     Compute the company's matching 401k contribution for the current month.
          
     - Parameters:
        - personalContribution: The current month's actual personal 401k
            contribution, that is *after* the personal annual limit has been
            applied.
        - yearToDate: The year-to-date sum of all employee and company 401k
            contributions
            - On entry: The sum should  *not* include any information for the
                current month.
            - On return: `yearToDate` will be updated to include the current
                months personal and company contributions.
        - splitInfo: `ContributionSplitInfo` instance specifying the company
            matching percentage and annual limits.
     
     - Returns: The company's matching 401k contribution for the current month.
     */
    private func company401kContribution(
        fromPersonalContribution personalContribution: Decimal,
        andCombinedYearToDateContributions yearToDate: inout Decimal,
        using splitInfo: ContributionSplitInfo) -> Decimal
    {
        yearToDate += personalContribution
        
        let companyCombinedContribution = roundToNearestPenny(
            percentage: splitInfo.companyMatchingPercentage,
            of: personalContribution
        )

        let companyContribution = clampContribution(
            companyCombinedContribution,
            whenCumulativeValue: yearToDate,
            exceeds: splitInfo.combined401kAnnualLimit
        )
        
        yearToDate += companyContribution
        
        return companyContribution
    }
```

Then `computeMonthlyContributions` becomes super simple, which was a large part of the reason for this refactoring in the first place.  Now whatever code that is dealing with months or some data structure for holding the `MonthlyContributions` instances doesn't need to know anything at all about the details of computing the contributions.

```swift
func computeMonthlyContributions(
    monthlyPay          : Decimal,
    using      splitInfo: ContributionSplitInfo) -> [MonthlyContributions]
{
    var contribution = MonthlyContributions()

    var monthlyContributions: [MonthlyContributions] = []
    monthlyContributions.reserveCapacity(ContributionMonth.count)

    for _ in ContributionMonth.allCases
    {
        contribution = contribution.nextMonth(pay: monthlyPay, using: splitInfo)
        monthlyContributions.append(contribution)
    }

    return monthlyContributions
}
```

All the globals you had defining the percentages and limits are changed to this, along with the code to call `computeMonthlyContributions`:

```swift
var monthlyPay: Decimal = 12758.0
let splitInfo =
    ContributionSplitInfo(personal401kPercentage: 100.0, rothPercentage: 16.0)

let monthlyContributions =
    computeMonthlyContributions(monthlyPay: monthlyPay, using: splitInfo)
```

The print loop code remains unchanged.

Now if you want, you can experiment with changing the pay in the loop, or with changing the percentages from month to month in a way that can happen in the real world.

Comment: Masterful! And I really appreciate how you explain each step/each change. It's really helping me learn these new-to-me concepts and tools. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful.  I updated the answer to add a refactored version that I think will make using it for a real-world app easier.

Comment: One aspect of this project that I did not explain is that the company contributions are independent of employee contributions. As the excel sheet shows, the company continues to directly contribute in March and April despite the employee having ceased (reached the limit). I altered the "let monthlyCompanyContribution" by replacing "of: combinedPersAmount" with "of: monthlyPay" for an improved result. However, May's print does not match the excel sheet: the 401a contribution is low and the company contributions are high. How do I prioritize 401a over company as they reach the $66k limit?

Comment: I don't have time to think this through thoroughly, but maybe calculate the 401a contribution before the company contribution, which may affect how `company401kContribution(fromPersonalContribution: andCombinedYearToDateContributions:using)` updates the year-to-date, if you're using my refactored version.  I'd probably put that code directly back in `nextMonth` first, then fix it to prioritize 401a.  After that's working, if it seems the right thing to do, extract it back out as a separate method.

Comment: BTW - if instead of a playground, you create a macOS command line tool project, you can set up unit tests for it - as well as letting you use the debugger, which will help tremendously.  If you don't already know it, learning how to write and run unit tests in Xcode is something you definitely should do.   And it's not that you'll run it at the command line, though you could.  Just run in it Xcode: cmd-R to run the program, cmd-U to run tests.  I cannot emphasize enough how helpful being able to use the debugger is.

Comment: File->New->Project.  Select macOS for the target platform, and then command line tool for the target type.  Copy all the code from your playground and paste it into the `Main.swift`.  The only thing from playgrounds that you won't get is live variable view on the right of the screen.  But, IMHO, you get something better: The debugger.  You can step line by line through the code, and view all the variables in the debugger.

Comment: using what you suggested about calculating the 401a contribution before the company contribution, within the refactored version I swapped the positions of the let statements for personal401aContributions and company401kContributions placing the "combinedYearToDateContributions += personal401aContribution" between the two. And within private func company401kContribution, under let companyCombinedContribution, I entered "of: monthlyPay." This seems to fully replicate the excel sheet. I appreciate the advice on macOS and debuggers. Will definitely try that out.

Comment: I'm trying to print the yearToDate totals of "Traditional", "Roth", "Pers401a", "CompanyTrad", and "CompanyRoth" much like how we have printed "Combined Year-To-Date." I see the "var combinedYearToDateContributions = yearToDateAll" under the extension, but I don't see a function which adds each month to the previous. All my attempts to duplicate this working sum-of-months into individualized sum-of-roth, sum-of-traditional, etc. have been unsuccessful because I don't understand how the yearToDateAll operator functions. I really appreciate the time you have spent thus far to teach!

Comment: `nextMonth` is being called on the month before the one it's creating, so its instance properties are the ones from the "previous" month.  Since there isn't a local variable called `yearToDateAll`, it refers to `self.yearToDateAll`.  If within `nextMonth` if you reference `self.yearToDateAll` or `self.roth`, etc...  those are the values of the "previous" month - that is from the instance of `MonthlyContributions` whose `nextMonth` method you are calling.

Comment: If it helps you think about it, you could start `nextMonth` with `let prevMonth = self`, and then thereafter refer to `prevMonth.yearToDateAll` or whatever other properties from `prevMonth`.  It's not logically necessary, and you won't want to do it as you get experienced writing Swift code, but maybe it makes it clear to you what's going on for now.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you!!

Comment: I'm unsuccessful in printing sum totals as I explained Jan 21st. Many different attempts. Two examples: within the MonthlyContributions extension inside the func nextMonth I created private func sumOfContribution(contribution1: Decimal, contribution2: Decimal) -> Decimal {let sumOfPers401k401a = contribution1 + contribution2 return sumOfPers401k401a} but the new var sumOfPers401k401a prints "0" for each month. I've tried moving it after the func nextMonth but still within the struct.   Still prints "0". This seems like a simple task that shouldn't be so perplexing.  Getting discouraged.

Comment: I figured out how to print out the totals for several individual categories. For personal Roth, I added "var sumOfPersRoth : Decimal = 0" to main struct and added "sumOfPersRoth : sumOfPersRoth + personalRoth" to "let contributions = self(..."   Now on to find out if I can call the December value to use in a formula. I.e. find the sum total of personal Roth total, personal Trad total, and 401a total. 

Comment: Inside `computeMonthlyContributions`, after the `for` loop, just before returning, the value of `contribution` is the `MonthlyContributions` instance for December.  Alternatively after calling `computeMonthlyContributions`, the value of the last element of the array it returns, `monthlyContributions` in your main print loop, is the `MonthlyContributions` instance for December.  We specifically set it up so that you can index into the array using `ContributionMonth`, so `monthlyContributions[.December]`.

Comment: `monthlyContributions.last` will also get you the `December` instance, but `.last` returns an `Optional<MonthlyContributions>`, so you have to unwrap it: `if let decContributions = monthlyContributions.last { ... }`

Comment: Thank you! This sounds very doable